# HTML Link defaulting to blue on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, anchor

This is probably something unbelievably simple that I'm missing, but for some reason my HTML button text is defaulting to blue, despite the text-decoration being set to none in the CSS.

The HTML is displayed as such -

```css
 .BecomeMemberBtn
    {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #34b629;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-size:11px;
    color:  #FFF;
    webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

```html
<p><a class="BecomeMemberBtn" href=".../become-a-member">Become A New Member</a></p>
```

When I run the code here, it displays in white, as it should, but when I test it on mobile devices (Android & iPhone), it displays in the default blue, which makes it unreadable against the green background of that button.

What makes it even more annoying is that I have another button, which uses more or less the exact same code and this displays correctly -

```css
  .MobSampleBtn
    {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #1e558d;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:  #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:10px;
    webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

```html
<p><a class="MobSampleBtn" href=".../Sample/True">Download Free Sample</a></p>
```

My question is - **why does BecomeMemberBtn default to blue text on mobile devices, yet MobileSampleBtn changes to white as intended?**

Comment: This has nothing to do with `text-decoration`

Comment: Also [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regular states are defined same way in your code, the difference may come from styles for `:visited` state. So make sure you also add styles for:

```css
.BecomeMemberBtn:visited,
.MobSampleBtn:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but would :visited only become enacted once the user presses said button? What seems to be happening is that the default color is always blue.

Comment: `:visited` is a style for the pages you visited, opened in browser. My guess is you already visited one of those two pages and therefore the color for one link is different. Styling the active link/button state (when user presses the button/link) is managed by adding `:active` selector.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `text-decoration` property only refers to the `underline`. What you want to (re)set it the `color` property.

If you're using external CSS files also make sure to clean your cache.

Comment: You know, I always thought that text-decoration applied to all formatting that would be applied to a button.